# Variadic template class implicitly converting

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have a class and need to validate that it's function calls are being called w/ the right parameters.  The function signature is always the same (sans 1 argument type). So, naturally I went for a templated approach.  So generally the validation policy would have a template parameter per data type it could handle:

```
using P = Policy<int, double, UserDefined>
```

Or something of that ilk.
I got it to compile, but the caveat is that if `double` and `int` (or anything a `double` can convert to actually) are both template parameters, the `double` will be implicitly converted.

The policy looks like this:

```
template <typename... T>
class BasicValidationPolicy { };

template <>
class BasicValidationPolicy<>
{
public:
    void RegisterSetHandler();
};

template <typename T, typename... Rest>
class BasicValidationPolicy<T, Rest...> : public BasicValidationPolicy<Rest...>
{
public:
    using SetHandler = std::function<void(int, T)>;
    
    void RegisterSetHandler(const SetHandler& handler)
    {
        m_setHandler = handler;
    }
    
    void Set(int n, const T& val) {
        if (m_setHandler) {
            m_setHandler(n, val);
        }
    }
    
private:
    SetHandler m_setHandler{nullptr};
};
```

The class that uses it...

```
template <typename ValidatorPolicy>
class MyClass : public ValidatorPolicy  {
public:

    void OnSetInt(int n, int64_t v)
    {
        ValidatorPolicy::Set(n, v);
    }
    
    void OnSetDouble(int n, double d)
    {
        ValidatorPolicy::Set(n, d);
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    using Policy = BasicValidationPolicy<int64_t, double>; // doesn't work
    MyClass<Policy> m;
    
    m.Policy::RegisterSetHandler([](int i, double value) {
        // by this point value is an int64_t
        std::cout << "Got double " << i << ", " << value << "\n";
    });
   
    double d{35.2135}; 
    m.OnSetDouble(1, d);
}
```

To boot, doing this *does* work

```
using Policy = BasicValidationPolicy<double, int64_t>;
```

So I guess I'm missing something about the template deduction.  Looks like it tries to match `double` against `std::int64_t` says "meh, good enough", and moves on.   Nice to know a way around it (kind of) but that looks like it would be very tricky to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complicated...

First of all: you have a recursive template class, `BasicValidationPolicy`, where you define two methods and you want that all methods, for all recursion steps of the class, are available.

Unfortunately, the definition of the methods in the derived classes hide the method in base classes.

To un-hide the inherited methods, you have to explicitly add a pair of `using`

```
using BasicValidationPolicy<Rest...>::Set;
using BasicValidationPolicy<Rest...>::RegisterSetHandler;
```

At this point, the code doesn't compile because you need a `Set()` and a `RegisterSetHandler()` in the ground case class. You have declared a dummy `RegisterSetHandler()` but not a dummy `Set()`. You have to add one, so the ground case become

```
template <>
class BasicValidationPolicy<>
{
public:
    void RegisterSetHandler();
    void Set();
};
```

Now your `MyClass<Policy>` object expose two `RegisterSetHandler()` methods (before only one): one receiving a `std::function<void(int, std::int64_t)>`, the other (before hidden) receiving a `std::function<void(int, double)>`.

But when you pass a lambda, you have a chicken-and-egg problem: the lambda can be converted to a `std::function` but isn't a `std::function`. So can't be used to deduce the template parameters of `std::function` because the types are to be known before to deduce them.

A possible solution is impose a lambda/`std::function` conversion in the call

```
// ..........................VVVVVVVVVVVVVV
m.Policy::RegisterSetHandler(std::function{[](int i, double value) {
                             // by this point value is an int64_t
                             std::cout << "Got double " << i << ", " << value << "\n";
                             }});
// ...........................^
```

using also the template deduction guides introduced in C++17.

So your code become

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename... T>
class BasicValidationPolicy { };

template <>
class BasicValidationPolicy<>
{
public:
    void RegisterSetHandler();
    void Set();
};

template <typename T, typename... Rest>
class BasicValidationPolicy<T, Rest...> : public BasicValidationPolicy<Rest...>
{
public:
    using SetHandler = std::function<void(int, T)>;

    using BasicValidationPolicy<Rest...>::Set;
    using BasicValidationPolicy<Rest...>::RegisterSetHandler;
    
    void RegisterSetHandler(const SetHandler& handler)
    {
        m_setHandler = handler;
    }
    
    void Set(int n, const T& val) {
        if (m_setHandler) {
            m_setHandler(n, val);
        }
    }
    
private:
    SetHandler m_setHandler{nullptr};
};

template <typename ValidatorPolicy>
class MyClass : public ValidatorPolicy  {
public:

    void OnSetInt(int n, int64_t v)
    {
        ValidatorPolicy::Set(n, v);
    }
    
    void OnSetDouble(int n, double d)
    {
        ValidatorPolicy::Set(n, d);
    }
};


int main ()
 {
   using Policy = BasicValidationPolicy<int64_t, double>; // doesn't work
   MyClass<Policy> m;
    
   m.Policy::RegisterSetHandler(std::function{[](int i, double value) {
                                std::cout << "Got double " << i << ", " << value << "\n";
                                }});
   
    double d{35.2135}; 
    m.OnSetDouble(1, d);
}
```

Comment: Rock star! I do my best to keep up w/ this stuff bug there are so many damn details. I will one day go through Nicolais' book but I fear most of it won't stick.   Seems like lambda's are sometimes false gods... I know they are not the same as std::function but I would have never considered passing in std::function like that... it makes so much sense now thinking of it.  Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @kiss-o-matic - " Seems like lambda's are sometimes false gods... " - Lamdas are extremely useful. Just consider that every tool has his limit.

Comment: Indeed.  I use them frequently... just gotta remember they're no silver bullet.

Answer (score 2):

There's a small alternative to the recursive definition that might be easier to work with...

```
template<typename T>
class ValidationPolicy {
  // Set/Register/etc
};

template <typename... Ts>
class BasicValidationPolicy : public ValidationPolicy<Ts>... {
 public:
  using ValidationPolicy<Ts>::Set...;
  using ValidationPolicy<Ts>::RegisterSetHandler...;
};
```

This can have some impacts on compile time and other aspects of development, though most likely relatively minor. For instance, if you have dozens of classes used in hundreds of different policy combinations in your app, the recursive definition will lead to many more distinct types and larger binaries to support that. For example, in the recursive definition `BasicValidationPolicy<T1, T2, T3>` and `BasicValidationPolicy<T3, T2, T1>` being used would generate 7 distinct types in a hierarchy (the empty one is shared in both expansions). The same thing in the flatter hierarchy would be 5 distinct types - one for each of `T1, T2, T3` and one for each combination. Adding in `BasicValidationPolicy<T2, T3, T1>` would add 3 more types recursively but 1 more type in the flat form.

The answer from @max66 isn't wrong, just something else to think about.

Comment: Indeed. Might check this out but compile time is indeed quite an issue with my current code base (which I am informed in MRs regularly).  I doubt this would push us over the edge but something to consider.

Comment: @kiss-o-matic - This solution is more elegant, clear and maintainable (IMHO) than the recursive one. Require C++17, because the variadic `using`, but you tagged C++17 so, I suppose, isn't a problem.

Comment: So I actually chewed on this a bit and I'm warming up to it.  It is a bit more elegant and I can reason a bit about it more.  Was a bit hard for me to wrap my head around the way the elipsis is used (for both using using and the inheriting part).  Ran it through cpp insights and it's a bit clearer.  

And yes, I'm compiling w/ C++ 17 so all good.  I know I need to keep chipping away at template magik but I always thing concepts are going to negate the need for a lot of that hard work.